# Can bluetooth pairing be used as a near-proximity authentication mechanism?

Tags: bluetooth

Is it possible to use Bluetooth pairing as an authentication mechanism? e.g. for a keyless entry system for a car. From a security standpoint, I am evaluating whether it would be feasible to pair your car to your phone to open the doors.

Are there any attacks which exist that could defeat this type of security?

Answer (score 0):

Searching on "bluetooth pairing security" brought up the following link as the second result: [Attack on the Bluetooth Pairing Process](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2005/06/attack_on_the_b_1.html). It's from 2005.

> There's a new cryptographic result against Bluetooth. Yaniv Shaked and Avishai Wool of Tel Aviv University in Israel have figured out how to recover the PIN by eavesdropping on the pairing process.

There's more, but the upshot is that if you want to use pairing, you'll want to rely on something else on top of it, rather than the pairing itself.

Comment: In 2005, BT pairing was insecure.  That doesn't apply at all today.  Since BT 2.1 (2007), BT devices use a newer form of pairing called Secure Simple Pairing.  It is actually very secure and not susceptible to the attacks mentioned in that paper.

Comment: @TJD: Thanks for the update; I haven't kept up-to-date on Bluetooth. Personally, I would still layer on an application identification scheme, but that's a result of my general distrust of any security standards having anything to do with telephony. More exactly, relying on pairing alone would still mandate verifying that the pairing protocol was conducted with an adequate protocol rather than the legacy ones.

Comment: @TJD: I went and read up on SSP. The pairing security isn't absolute in all cases, and takes some care to use correctly. See [Analyzing the secure simple pairing in Bluetooth v4.0](https://dspace.lboro.ac.uk/dspace-jspui/bitstream/2134/8295/1/blue6.pdf). And even given that, the structure of the protocol is such that it's vulnerable to lazy implementation that use fixed nonces and suchlike, against all crypto common sense; even so, they appear in the wild. ... As a result, I stand by my recommendation to implement identification on top of Bluetooth pairing.

Comment: I'm not against adding another layer of identification.  But SSP is pretty secure.  No amateur hackers are breaking it, maybe government-strength attacks could.  Note that SSP is done inside the BT hardware (99.9% devices made by 3 companies), and verified during device certification.  So there's not much room for someone to have written a sloppy software implementation.  You wouldn't see so many BT keyboards in use if SSP wasn't strong because then you could just build a wireless keylogger.

Comment: I agree about stealing keystrokes. The threat model changes, though, if you can start to steal cars with some kind of active intervention.